# What is an appropriate and general function signature associated with a probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, soft-question, notation

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability distribution $f_X$

> Then $f_X$ is a function,
>
> $f_X : A \to B, c \mapsto d$

What exactly are $A,B,c,d$?

I am sorry if this question is basic, as I am from a computer science background and we do not usually specify these functions rigorously. In fact I am reading a paper right now and it says "let $p$,$q$, be probability distributions that generates data $X,Y$" - not very rigorous I tell you.

Comment: It is saying: $f_X$ is a function with domain $A$ and codomain $B$, and maps $c\in A$ to $d\in B$.

Comment: @user10354138 I know what it semantically means. I am wondering what $A,B,c,d$ should be. Is $A = \mathbb{R}$?? What determines what $A,B,c,d$ are?